Confused about whether to use fftshift in the MATLAB code for implementing the S-FFT algorithm for simulation Fresnel diffraction
S-FFT stands for single fast Fourier transformation, it’s based on Fresnel diffraction integral.
(The foumula is here, https://i.sstatic.net/M6SneUxp.jpg, sorry I can't upload pictures yet)
I have the following MATLAB code for implementing the S-FFT algorithm, fftshift is used in the first diffraction but not in the second one, because adding fftshift to the second diffraction will give the wrong result.
the result is here(https://i.sstatic.net/GPONX8iQ.jpg).
The way I understand fftshift is that it shifts the zero-frequency component to the center of the spectrum, so why using fftshift in the second diffraction gives the wrong result?
r = 512; c = r;                                         % sampling rate

Uo = zeros(c, r);                                       % initialize the object
d = 30; a = 10;                                         % grating constant

for n = 1:d:c
    Uo(n:n+a, :) = 1;
end
for m = 1:d:r
    Uo(:, m:m+a) = 1;
end
Uo = Uo(1:c, 1:r);                                      % the object is a grating

figure, imshow(Uo, []), title('object')

lamda = 6328e-10; k = 2*pi/lamda;                       % wavelength and wave number
f = 0.004; Lo = 0.001;                                  % focal length and size of the lens
D1 = 5e-5; D2 = 5e-5;

% =================================================================
% diffraction from the object to the lens using S-FFT
xo = linspace(-Lo/2, Lo/2, r); yo = linspace(-Lo/2, Lo/2, c);
[xo, yo] = meshgrid(xo, yo);                            % coordinate on the object

do = 0.0041;                                            % distance from the object to the lens
L = r*lamda*do/Lo;                                      % size of the diffracting pattern on the lens

xl = linspace(-L/2, L/2, r); yl = linspace(-L/2, L/2, c);
[xl, yl] = meshgrid(xl, yl);                            % coordinates on the lens

F0 = exp(1j*k*do)/(1j*lamda*do)*exp(1j*k/2/do*(xl.^2+yl.^2));
F = exp(1j*k/2/do*(xo.^2+yo.^2));                       % S-FFT
FU = (Lo*Lo/r/r).*fftshift(fft2(Uo.*F));                % fftshift here
U1 = F0.*FU;
I1 = U1.*conj(U1);
figure, imshow(I1, []), colormap('gray'), title('intensity distribution at the front surface of the lens')

% ==================================================================
% light field at the back surface of the lens
Ulyp = U1.*exp(-1j*k*(xl.^2+yl.^2)/2/f);

% ==================================================================
% diffraction from the lens to the back focal plane using S-FFT
dlf = f;                                                % distance from the lens to the back focal plane
Lyp = r*lamda*dlf/L;                                    % size of the final diffraction pattern

xf = linspace(-Lyp/2, Lyp/2, r); yf = linspace(-Lyp/2, Lyp/2, c);
[xf, yf] = meshgrid(xf, yf);                            % coordinate on the back focal plane
F0 = exp(1j*k*dlf)/(1j*lamda*dlf)*exp(1j*k/2/dlf*(xf.^2+yf.^2));
F = exp(1j*k/2/dlf*(xl.^2+yl.^2));                      % S-FFT
Uf = L^2/r^2.*fft2(Ulyp.*F);                            % no fftshift here, why?
Uf = Uf.*F0;
I2 = Uf.*conj(Uf);
figure, imshow(I2, [0, max(I2(:))/100]), colormap('pink'), title('final diffraction pattern')

I tried adding fftshift at the second position & removing the fftshift at the first position, but neither got me the correct answer.
